# Overriding "view" level properties in Ember 2.x core components

Tags: javascript, css, ember.js

I've come across an issue that i'm sure developers must have encountered before when using Ember 2.x and trying to do full-page divs.

In the old days of Ember, you could override view properties such as `class` by using the following syntax:

```
var ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['container'],
    ...
});

module.exports = ApplicationView;
```

In Ember 2.x, the concept of Views is now deprecated, but the concept of components requires that you use a `-` in your component name, which obviously doesn't work for overriding either your `application` or `index` core views.

The way that i'm fixing this is retaining my `views/application.js` structure in my application, but changing to:

```
import 'Ember' from ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['container'],
});
```

This works, but it just feels...dirty?  Has anyone come across, or know of, a more "official" way of doing this, because I can't be the only person who's trying to make a full page div in Ember 2.x and thus needing to apply css to the application-level div.

Answer (score 0):

The [recommended way to do this is to use an extra element in the template](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_routable-views), with any necessary logic or computed properties in the application controller.

For example, if you want a class name depending on the route name, you could have this computed in your `ApplicationController`:

```
currentPathClassName: Ember.computed('currentPath', function() {
  let currentPath = this.get('currentPath').replace(/\./g, '-');
  return `${currentPath}-route`;
})
```

Then in your `application.hbs` template:

```
<div class={{currentPathClassName}}>
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

This will result in an additional nested div, but I can't think of any situation where that would cause problems.